# Inconsistency about ruby 'main' object

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

Ruby is pretty consistent about classes and objects. However, when it comes to top-level method declaration, that rule somehow breaks down. For example,

```
$ puts self # => main
$ puts self.class # => Object
```

However, the methods declared in the context of this `main` object are somehow available as private methods of class `Object`.

Is there any logical explanation for this? I understand that this is very convenient as these methods appear as "stand-alone functions", but taking it just as "it just is so" breaks the otherwise consistent rules, as normally you have to define a method in the context of a class for it to be a method of that class. However, the `main` object is not class `Object`, nor is it a class at all.

**Re-framing my question:**
In what scope does the method gets declared inside ruby's REPL? {class Object/ object main or module Kernel}

Regarding private nature of methods declared in REPL, plz see the following example:

```
def my_method # "a method declared in REPL"
  puts "method called"
end

# calling my_method in REPL aka top-level scope
my_method # => "method called"
[].my_method # => private method `my_method' called for []:Array (NoMethodError)
Array.my_method # => private method `my_method' called for Array:Class (NoMethodError)
```

Q: If my_method is defined as a private method under class Object, then why is self set to main instead of class Object. If someone says that its not under private scope, then why am I getting above mentioned error?

Comment: [What is the Ruby Top-Level?](http://banisterfiend.wordpress.com/2010/11/23/what-is-the-ruby-top-level/)

Comment: I've updated my response to include your sample code and it's result in 1.9.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I'm not sure I fully understand the question, I'll try to answer:

When you're working inside `irb` you're really working in a context like this:

```
class Object
  # you're here
end
```

So, if you declare a method inside the REPL you're actually declaring it inside `main`'s class:

```
ruby-1.9.3-rc1 :001 > def foo; end
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.3-rc1 :002 > self.class.public_methods.include?(:foo)
 => true
```

I'm not sure where you get the idea that the methods defined there are private to the class (but again, I might be misunderstanding the question).

The class you're inside in `irb` includes the `Kernel` module so that's why you have access to its functions (which, since you're inside the class, appear as stand-alone functions even though they're regular methods):

```
ruby-1.9.3-rc1 :003 > self.class.included_modules
 => [Kernel]
```

This would make it consistent with the typical Ruby behavior and indeed, `main` is just `self` inside the Object class.

If you call `self` you'll receive `main` because that's the way it's instructed to do it through inspect. We can remove the `#to_s` method from `self` and see the real value:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :001 > self
 => main 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :002 > class << self; remove_method :to_s; end
 => #<Class:#<Object:0x007fc08387af00>> 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :003 > self
 => #<Object:0x007fc08387af00 @prompt={:PROMPT_I=>"ruby-1.9.3-p0 :%03n > ", :PROMPT_S=>"ruby-1.9.3-p0 :%03n%l> ", :PROMPT_C=>"ruby-1.9.3-p0 :%03n > ", :PROMPT_N=>"ruby-1.9.3-p0 :%03n?> ", :RETURN=>" => %s \n", :AUTO_INDENT=>true}>
```

*Edit: Before moving forward I think you should clarify which Ruby version are you using, see the sample below for 1.9.3:*

```
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :001 > def my_method
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :002?>     puts "method called"
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :003?> end
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :004 > 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :005 >   [].my_method
method called
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :006 > Array.my_method 
method called
```

Comment: If I am inside main's class i.e. class Object in REPL, then why is self set to main and not to Object? For eg: class MyClass; p self; end # => MyClass

Comment: I've added extra samples to the response to clarify why this is happening :)

Comment: Thanks. That works. I am using ruby-1.9.3-p194. However, if I write the same code in file test.rb and run it using $ ruby test.rb, it shows the error I documented above. Any reason for the anomaly?

Comment: That's becaue of the way the interpreter works, see http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/iseq.c#201. If you write `public` at the top of the file it should work as in `irb`.

Answer (score 2):

IMO top-level methods are defined <s>in the context of `Kernel` module</s>, not `Object` class so they end up both in `Object` instance and class methods (because `Class` class includes `Kernel` too):

```
def a_method
  "inside a_method"
end

public :a_method

p Object.a_method
p Object.new.a_method
p self.a_method
p Kernel.a_method
```

which allows them to be used in any context.

**UPDATE**: It's even more simple, `Module.superclass` is an `Object`, so when we define something in `Object` it will end up as `Module` instance method too. And `Class.superclass` is a `Module`, so it ends up as a class methods for all classes too. And because `Kernel.class` is a `Module`, `Kernel.a_method` is an instance method of class `Module`. Well, really simple?

Comment: I am really surprised at last line executing well. Can anyone confirm if top-level methods are actually defined in the context of Kernal and not Object class. Also, why is self set to main (obj of class Object) and not to module/class?

Comment: Cool. That explains why it gets called on Kernel too. But then methods not defined in the context of Kernel module. It works because Object includes Kernel module and Module class inherits objects. So, Kernel, though sitting above Object can access Object methods. $ class MyClass; end; MyClass.ancestors # => [MyClass, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking why you can define a method/function on top-level, while you're not inside any class, then the answer would be that you *can also* define a method in an object for the class it belongs. Let's see an example.

```
class C
  def f
    def g
      'g'
    end
    'f'
  end
end

C.new.g # NoMethodError: undefined method `g' for #<C:0x0>
C.new.f # => 'f'
C.new.g # => 'g'
```

It is not recommended to do this, but it is consistent in this case.

Comment: Here I think you are not defining method 'g' inside an object, but defining it inside the class only because class scope if C

Comment: I am not sure what did you mean. `def g` is called in the context of C's instance, it's different than `def f` which is called in the context of C's class (itself).

Comment: Common mistake. `def f` and `def g` are in fact called in the same context, and both methods end up being instance methods of C (as you show in your example). Then only difference is that you have to call `f` to define `g`.